# Fortify Scan Correction

Tags: asp.net

I am new to HP Fortify, and need help with some of the identified scan errors.  The line that marked with stars was rated critical, and I don't know a different way to do it:

```
List<string> listNames = GetUsers();

if (listNames.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var name in listNames)
        ***lbLookup.Items.Add(name);    //lbLookup is an asp:ListBox
}
```

Comment: may be you need to check NullOrEmpty condition before adding

Comment: the checking of count does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my own question:

List listNames = GetUsers();

if (listNames.Count > 0)

{

```
      foreach (var name in listNames)

      {
           String item = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name);
           lbLookup.Items.Add(item);
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if(listNames.Count > 0)
```

checks if your list contains any elements or it is empty.

But you should also check every element if it is null or empty string before adding it to your ListBox. Becuase i
so additional check for each element may solve your problem. Try this :

```
if (listNames.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var name in listNames)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) // making sure that null items would not added to ListBox
            lbLookup.Items.Add(name);    
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do is checking that your asp:ListBox object is not null before adding elements to its Items.

Comment: Well,  GetUsers  function checks if the names are not null or empty, then add names to list.  But I wanted to give it a shot, I tried what you suggested, and analyze source code again, it still shows that line of code in its Critical issue list.

Comment: You mean the GetUsers?  It does not matter much, since Fortify identified the lines of code it thinks those having issues. In this case,  lbLookup.Items.Add(name);

Comment: Not GetUsers() method, I am asking about complete method for which you have posted the code in quesrion

Comment: Have you tried null check of ListBox object bfore adding items to it??